# how to create variable in xslt 1

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

could you please tell me how how to combine xml in variable ?

**Input xml**

```
<video>
    <a>
        <c>
            <d>hello</d>
            <d>jjjj</d>
        </c>
    </a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>test</d>
            <d>sss</d>
        </c>
    </b>
</video>
```

**Code**

```
    <xsl:template match="video">
        <xsl:variable name="videoList">
            <video>
                <xsl:copy-of select="//./a/c"></xsl:copy-of>
                <xsl:copy-of select="//./b/c"></xsl:copy-of>

            </video>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$videoList"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<video>
    <c>
        <d>hello</d>
        <d>jjjj</d>
    </c>
    <c>
        <d>test</d>
        <d>sss</d>
    </c>
</video>
```

**Expected output**

```
<video>
    <c>
        <d>hello</d>
        <d>jjjj</d>

        <d>test</d>
        <d>sss</d>
    </c>

</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is too abstract to be sure what you're after. One way to get the result you're showing is to define your variable as:

```
<xsl:variable name="videoList">
        <video>
            <c>
                <xsl:copy-of select="a/c/d | b/c/d"/>
            </c>
        </video>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: it is not current answer..pls check expected output

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think you need a variable? You can just do:

```
<xsl:template match="video">
   <video>
     <c>
        <xsl:copy-of select=".//d"/>
     </c>
  </video>
</xsl:template>
```